# consistency in available categories for one-hot encoding

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, xgboost, one-hot-encoding

Let's say that I have two datasets, one for training and one for prediction.

In both datasets I have the same categorical variables that I wish to one-hot encode using sklearn's `preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()`.

Next, let's look at variable X's possible unique values: `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']`

So, variable X exists in both the training and the testing data-set. However, only values `'a'` and `'b'` appear in the training set, while only `'c'`, `'d'` and `'e'` appear in the test set.

So, if I apply the following code to these two data sets:

```
enc1 = pre.OneHotEncoder()
to_encode = train_df.select_dtypes(include='object')
encoded = enc1.fit_transform(to_encode).toarray()
dum_df = pd.DataFrame(encoded, columns=enc1.get_feature_names(to_encode.columns))
train_df = train_df.join(dum_df)
train_df.drop(to_encode.columns, axis=1, inplace=True)

# And repeat, just replace train_df with test_df
```

I get two one-hot encoded dataframes. However, their dimensions are going to be different because some of the values in the training set did not appear in the test set (and vice versa).

Assuming that I've trained an algorithm on the training set:

1. **What happens when I feed the data from the test set into a machine learning algorithm that was trained on the training set which had
   different dimensions?**
2. **Will the algorithm care that some columns of data are missing?** Specifically I am using `XGBoost.XGBRegressor()`, but also I am interested in knowing if there is a general answer as well.

Comment: 1. You don't/can't. Whatever features you use to train you need to use to test. If your features were [a, b, c] but your testing data only has [d,e] then it doesn't get 2 columns for d and e, it gets 3 columns of all 0s since [a, b, c] are your features and you don't have them. You can look into more sophisticated ways of splitting the data (stratified shuffle split) to ensure all categories are represented if that's necessary.

Comment: @ALollz I am constrained in the data split, as the 'test' data is from a kaggle competition and comes pre split. Their test data for some categories doesn't have the full range of possible unique values. 

I just read that if I use the same encoder that was fit on the training set, it will insert columns of all 0's for the test set encoding, if it doesn't have those values. That seems to be a reasonable alternative. What do you think?

Comment: You shouldn't apply enc1.fit_transform() to test set, it should be only enc1.transform() because if you fit again, you are learning from the test set. Then, in OneHotEncoder you can use the option handle_unknown="ignore" to avoid errors if new categories not seen before appear. The algorithms don't manage missing values, for that you have to impute before: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html

Comment: @jjsantoso but then, I will lose data for those unknown categories. Perhaps the best bet is to join the test and training data for the purpose of encoding all possible categories. Then, I can split them out later for training and prediction.

Comment: @rocksNwaves that could be, but you never know what is coming with totally new unseen data, you need to be able to handle all that cases. You can create a dict with the known categories, map to a new column in a way that unknown categories are missing values. Then use imputation to fill missing with a new category.  You will end with a new category that collect all unknown categories. Is not perfect, but you don't lose all information.

Answer (score 0):

I think align is what you are looking for. As the example below

```
train = pd.get_dummies(train)   #assume it  gives (1451, 221)  
test = pd.get_dummies(test)    #assume it gives (1459, 206)
# now doing alignment of train and test will do the trick  
final_train, final_test = train.align(test, join='inner', axis=1)  # inner join
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this will still result in lost data, even though the shape will be correct. I decided to go with joining my test and training data frames for the purpose of one-hot, since there is no danger of data-leakage in this case.

Comment: That is the case of data leakage indeed . if before merge you do the one hot and say you dont have column "X" but after merge you get column X because of the train , this means that your test now have some ideas about your train. In practice your column X in test data will contain all zeros even if you do that!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how that is true. Every algorithm I have dealt with requires that the test data be the same shape as the training data. If the columns are not the same, you will throw an error until you include those missing columns. Since one hot encoding relies on either a dictionary of possible values or it auto generates columns based on available data, there are only two ways to proceed. 1.) Manually tell it about the missing categories. 2.) Merge for one hot, then split again. Either way, the result is the same, and necessary.